# const fn vs inline attribute

Tags: rust, inline, compile-time-constant

In the following example, I believe that when the function `Struct::new` is called, its body will be inlined (copied) to the call-site because of the `#[inline]` attribute. This will result in more code being generated and slower compile times but better runtime performance because of the eliminated function call.

```
impl Struct {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // initialization code
    }
}
```

Nowadays `const fn` are stable on Rust. When someone declares a function as `const`, it should allow the compiler to evaluate it at compile time.

```
impl Struct {
    pub const fn new() -> Self {
        // initialization code
    }
}
```

Does declaring the function as `const` and omitting the `#[inline]` attribute offer the same trade-offs as the code in the previous example (because the function is evaluated in compile-time and its result is "inlined" to the call-site)? Should we replace all the `#[inline]` attributes with `const`? If they are not same, what are the differences?

Comment: I imagine that with reasonably high optimization levels neither the const or inline attributes help. If anything they might hinder other optimizations. Or in other words the answer to this question is let the compiler do its job, it is probably smarter than you.

Comment: @PiRocks `inline` is a hint, so it shouldn't hinder optimizations, and it can actually help with cross-crate inlining, which isn't performed by default ([source](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-inline-cross-crate-function-in-2020/36963/2)). `const` shouldn't hinder optimizations, it just means that the function can be called in constant contexts. Yes, the compiler is smart, but it's not perfect, and Rust is a systems language used in many different contexts. "The compiler is smarter than you" is not a helpful response to a question honestly and clearly asking about the tradeoffs involved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#[inline]` and `const` are completely different things and the one is not a superset of the other:

- `#[inline]` *guides* the compiler to not make a heuristic decision whether or not to inline the function body into the caller. The compiler is still free to disregard this attribute entirely or at specific call-sites if it so chooses for whatever reason since inlining does not change the program's behaviour in any observable way.
- `const` is part of the function's signature and *guarantees* that the function *can be* (but not necessarily *is*) evaluated at compile time. The compiler may choose to evaluate the function body at compile time if it can, yet it is free to move that to runtime. The reason to make a function `const` is that the possibility to be evaluated in a const-context is part of the function's signature, guaranteeing this property in a semver-stable way. That is, a function that can be called in a const-context should not suddenly lose this property without a semver-bump.

The above is the reason why `const` is part of the publicly documented function signature but `#[inline]` is not.

So no, do not blindly exchange `#[inline]` for `const`.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that const evaluation only works if all function arguments can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: And that both can be used together so that the function has more chance to be inlined when not const-evaluated.